# Query Store Force Plan feature doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-store

Query Store Force plan feature doesn't appear to be enforcing the plan.

I'm aware of [Query Store - Forced Doesn’t Always Mean Forced](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2016/09/18/query-store-forced-doesn-t-always-mean-forced.aspx); however, my plan may not change insignificantly, but query optimizer may continue to choose incorrect indexes, loop choices etc.

Basically: it doesn't honor my forced plan choice. I've forced many plans and *It Just Doesn't Work*.

1. There are 0 failure counts or reasons when I look at `sys.query_store_plan` `force_failure_count`.
2. Extended event `query_store_plan_forcing_failed` doesn't yield anything. 0 Events.

For example, a plan which was forced on 20.09. Only 1 compilation happened to use forced plan.

[image: Plans for Query]

The plans differ wildly, one using Hash Match join with INDEX 1, the other using Loop Join with INDEX 2.

[image: Different plans]

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB3210089) - 13.0.4202.2 (X64)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [sys.query_store_plan (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql) (emphasis added)

> #### Plan forcing limitations
>
> Query Store has a mechanism to enforce Query Optimizer to use certain execution plan. However, **there are some limitations that can prevent a plan to be enforced**.
>
> First, if the plan contains following constructions:
>
> - Insert bulk statement.
> - Reference to an external table
> - Distributed query or full-text operations
> - Use of Global queries
> - **Cursors**
> - Invalid star join specification

You are using a cursor.

---

You can often force a cursor plan with a plan guide instead. See [Using the USE PLAN Query Hint on Queries with Cursors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190788(v=sql.105).aspx).

And yes, I agree that the current situation does not make for the best user experience. I would expect that attempting to force a plan for something that cannot (currently) be forced would raise an error or warning, or log something. You could log a [Feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) to request an improvement in this area.

---

As of SQL 2019 CTP 2.3 forcing query execution plan for Fast Forward and Static cursors [are supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#query-store-plan-forcing-support-for-fast-forward-and-static-cursors-ctp-23)

> Query Store now supports the ability to force query execution plans for fast forward and static T-SQL and API cursors. Forcing is now supported via `sp_query_store_force_plan` or through SQL Server Management Studio Query Store reports.