# Query Store- force plan not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, query-store, query-performance

Have similar issue as was ask in other [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187269/query-store-force-plan-feature-doesnt-work).

In my case none of cases from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) seems to apply

Can something else be the reason? Schema changes not happening, but after index maintenance new plan is generated and forced one gets ignored.

[image]

Query:

- has lot of joins and union. there is query hint used in joins (maybe that is the reson?)
- select list contains "*"